# Implementing a key-sensitive monad bind for key-value Map

Tags: haskell, list, monad, dictionary

Based on the List monad I set out to define `Monad` instances for the `Map` type from `Data.Map`, to perform chained unions and folds on `Map`s like lists, but with the efficient sorting and merging of `Map`s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import qualified Data.Map as M

instance Monad (M.Map Integer) where
  return = M.singleton 0
  f >>= g = M.foldr (\a -> M.union (g a)) M.empty f
```

This compiles fine but I would like `g` to be sensitive to the key of each value that it operates on. That would allow the output of `g` to have staggered keys for richer unioning behaviour. This is fictional Haskell and doesn't typecheck but it would be nice to have:

```
type PairMap (a,b) = Map a b

instance Monad PairMap where
  return :: (k,a) -> PairMap (k,a)
  return (k,a) = M.singleton k a
  (>>=) :: PairMap (k,a) -> ((k,a) -> PairMap (k',a')) -> PairMap (k',a'))
  f >>= g = M.foldrWithKey (\(k,a) -> M.union (g k a)) M.empty f
```

If you replace `PairMap (a,b)` with `[(a,b)]` you get exactly the List monad back again. But GHC doesn't allow me to cheat and turn the two parameters of `Map` into one pair. The best I could manage was something like this: (I had to add the `Ord c` constraint to typecheck with unions)

```
class PairMonad m where
  return2 :: a -> b -> m a b
  (>>==) :: (Ord c) => m a b -> (a -> b -> m c d) -> m c d

instance PairMonad M.Map where
  return2 = M.singleton
  f >>== g = M.foldrWithKey (\k a -> M.union (g k a)) M.empty f
```

I hope you can see how similar this is to the `PairMap` dream, so it should be possible to do this more elegantly with established monadic magic or other concepts related to monads. *I don't need it to be a monad as long as I can achieve that "key-sensitive bind."*

**Last Resort**

- If there's no way to do this elegantly then I'll resort to collapsing
  each `Map` to a key-value list `[(a,b)]` and use the List monad.
- One might suggest including the key into the value to help `g` compute on the key, but I see that as contaminating the value with extraneous information.

Comment: Could you give an example of how `g k a` would differ from `g a`? Technically I believe that if `g` could look at the keys it would violate the monad laws. However, there may be another data structure or formulation which can accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: for example if they keys `k` were integers and `a`'s were lists then I might want `g k [True,False,True] == M.fromList [((k,1),True),((k,2),False),((k,3),True)]` such that the `Map` resulting from the bind has pairs of integers as keys which are sorted in lexicographic order, remembering the prior `Map` structure. I wouldn't be able to achieve this in `g a` which can't compute on the key of `a`. I just want to know if there's an existing solution to this, it doesn't have to be a monad.

Answer (score 3):

Even if it had valid Haskell syntax, your `PairMap` "monad" *isn't actually a monad*, because it forces the result type of the bind operation to be a pair, which prevents the ability to use it in contexts where a pair is not required (e.g. the `sequence` function couldn't accept it, because it returns `m t a` where `m` is the monad type and `t` is a traversable type, i.e. the result is not a pair so can't work with it). I don't have a proof right now, but intuitively speaking, *this must be true for any attempt to turn `Map` into a monad other than by using constant keys* as any such attempt can only work by adding additional structural requirements that would prevent your "monad" from working with existing users of the Monad typeclass.

You're actually looking at a generalisation of Monads that does not fit into the existing class's restrictions. It is possible that you may be able to make it coexist with existing generalisations of Monads; the one that jumps to mind is `Control.Arrow.Arrow`, which already has an understanding built into the typeclass of using it to operate on pairs, so is potentially a much better fit to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Looking up `Arrow`s on Jules' suggestion brought me to the `Category` typeclass, which allowed me to engineer what I wanted below:

```
import qualified Control.Category as C
import qualified Data.Map as M

newtype KeyValMorphism k a b = KeyVal ((k, a) -> M.Map k b)

instance (Ord k) => C.Category (KeyValMorphism k) where
  id = KeyVal (uncurry M.singleton)
  KeyVal g . KeyVal f = KeyVal (M.foldrWithKey (\k a -> M.union (g (k,a))) M.empty . f)
```

I'm slightly dissatisfied with this because:

- The `newtype` wrapper which prevents me from using raw functions
  `(k,a) -> M.Map k b`, but for type checking reasons I think this is
  the best that can be done.
- The type `k` of the keys needs to be fixed throughout the computations, which fits my application and seems a reasonable sacrifice for the simplicity of this instance declaration.